# Create players to class with for loop

Tags: python

I try to create throwing a dice.

First, the player chooses the number of players:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome.")

while True:
    try:
        number_of_players = int(input("\nEnter the number of players: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("\nEnter the correct number of players.")

throw(number_of_players)
```

I have class of players:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, number_of_player):
        self.number_of_player = number_of_player
        self.number_of_throws = 0

    def add_throw(self):
        self.number_of_throws += 1

    def number_of_throws(self):
        print(self.number_of_throws)

    def number_of_player(self):
        print(self.number_of_player)
```

And class of dice:

```
class Dice:
    def random_number(self):
        print(randint(1, 6))
```

And there is `throw()` function:

```
def throw(number_of_players):
    dice = Dice()

    for number_of_player in range(pocet_hracu):
        player[number_of_player] = Player(number_of_player)
        random_number = dice.random_number()
    print("Player {} threw {}.".format(player[number_of_player].number_of_player(), random_number)
```

The problem is in `throw()` function.

I need to have variables as `player[0] = Player(0)` ... `player[number_of_player] = Player(number_of_player)`.

But why?

Comment: Shouldn't the `random_number()` function in `Dice` `return randint(1, 6)` and not `print` it?